# Getting error python setup.py build_ext --inplace VC C++ 14.0 required

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, darkflow

While executing the setup.py for TensorFlow code to run darknet, I run into error regarding Microsoft Visual C++ edition.

Command:

```
C:\Users\usename\Desktop\Dark\darkflow>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Output:

```
running build_ext
building 'darkflow.cython_utils.nms' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this after installing Visual Studio 14 build tool 
Link to download [visualstudiobuildtool](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe)